# How to create a class that connects to a Database with no datasets, query or table components of any kind?

Tags: delphi, ms-access

The problem I have is I want to create a class in delphi that connects to a MS access database, but I am not allowed to use datasets, query or table component of any kind. I have found a way to connect to the data base (The code as follows):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

conn := TADOConnection.Create(nil);

conn.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Program Files (x86)\Delphi7SE\Projects\Bpl\Database11.mdb;Persist Security Info=False';
conn.LoginPrompt := False;
qr := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
try
  conn.Connected := True;
except on e: EADOError do
  begin
      MessageDlg('Error while connecting', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
      Exit;
end;
end;

try
conn.Open;
  qr.Connection := conn;
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;
  qr.SQL.Text := 'Select * FROM Customer';
  qr.Open;
  while NOT qr.Eof do
  begin
      //ListBox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(qr.SQL.Add('SELECT FirstName FROM Customer;')));
      ListBox1.Items.Add(qr.FieldByName('FirstName').Value);
      qr.Next;
  end;
  conn.Close;
finally
  conn.Free;
  qr.Free;
end;

end;
```

I want to put that into a class, but I do not know how, as I have only done delphi in grade 10 to 12.

Comment: Does *"I am not allowed to use no datasets"* mean that you're allowed to use datasets ? If not, you can use just a connection object to connect to a database and execute SQL queries. How to wrap a certain functionality in a class is the very basic that you should know (or at least know where to find).

Comment: It means that I am not allowed to use them. True I understand where you are coming from, but my main thing is that I have last used delphi in 2008 and i have done other things during that time so it means I have last did delphi in school.

Comment: Can you give the reason why sou are not allowed to use datasets? This would help to find the direction where the answer should lead you.

Comment: It is for a job application. They set the constraints on how I am suppose to do it.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still lost. You want to create a class which will be able to connect to a database ? Well, then use just a `TADOConnection` object wrapped in [`a class`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Class).

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do, and I have looked at that, but the thing is I am stumped at how to set up the functions and procedures for that class to connect to the database. I know how to do it in C#.

Comment: use `TAccessApplication` component

Comment: How would I go about doing so? When I did delphi at school, we didn't go into these components, that is why it is hard for me to carry out this simple application.

Comment: Mmmm... in my opinion the school is not what teaches the exact components, but what teaches to self-learning and finding the information...
Did you programmed in Microsoft VBA ? Generally VBA code for Access would be translated to Delphi code almost exactly, as they rely to the same COM object model

Comment: @UweRaabe perhaps they use Delphi Starter ?

Comment: Thats true school didn't teach me all of it and no didn't use Microsoft VBA. We used Delphi 7 I can't remember if it was a start or not. Long time ago.

Comment: In your code you use `TADOQuery`. but you say *"I am not allowed to use datasets, query or table component of any kind"*...

Comment: Maybe this question is about some kind of ORM and direct connection from TDataSet to TDBGrid is forbidden (thats why a ListBox is used for presentation). That would make sense to me

Comment: @SirRufo, I bet the solution is really simple and all you need is a `TADOConnection` with `Execute` to do anything you want. I have already seen such question here on SO, with the exactly same story, but I can't find it (It was probably deleted)

Comment: @kobik Only Execute did not fill the ListBox and this is also asked ... but we can dicuss this for hours, because it is not clear, whats being really asked ;o) - Maybe Execute is one part of it ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo, `Execute` can return a `_Recordset` do fill the ListBox.

Comment: @kobik I know that, it's a part of it, as I said ;o) Best use would be Excute, fill an ObjectList and fill the ListBox from that  (very simple and small ORM)

Answer (score 5):

It's not very clear what your prospective employer is asking for but I'm leaving you this answer because it's too long for a comment.

First, you are using a `TADOQuery` component that created in code. This is exactly the same as using a `TADOQuery` that you dropped onto a form.

Database access without components in its strictest sense would mean you shouldn't use any class which descends from TComponent. If you can use a TADOConnection, it is possible to execute SQL statements directly from that TADOConnection, but this is simply an "interview question" technique that would never be used in the real world.

Secondly, if your desire is to connect to a database available via an OLEDB provider, such as ADO, it is possible to go directly to Microsoft's OLEDB or ADO COM interfaces and connect to them.  Delphi is quite good at consuming any COM interface you can name. But implementing all of that in a way that is actually more than a hack or a demo is far beyond the scope of anything I would expect anybody to be able to complete in the period of a job interview.

If you had a database that had no COM/ADO/OLEDB interface capabilities, it is possible to write your own classes that load up the database client code, perhaps as a DLL, and talk to the database that way. You could even write your own ODBC client in delphi.  After all, whatever underlying techniques are used by these pre-written and pre-tested database access components could be done by you.  Would that be a smart way for your employer to run their business? No.  But since you can even study the source of any of the existing components, and since your employer might want to hire someone who could find and fix a bug in a component even if it was not one they wrote, this might be what they are looking for; Technical knowledge that extends deep into the stack.

My best guess is that your interviewer wants to know if you're an inquisitive developer who understands the whole technology stack, or a cargo-cult programmer who only understands the top level of the technology stacks you use.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi comes with `TAccessApplication` component (actually up to 3 ones, for Office 2000+, Office XP+ and Office 2010+)

You the component to connect to Access application (and/or launch it) and control it.

Google around for Delphi interaction using COM or OLE Automation. You'd get miriads of samples about controlling Word or Excel, but generally the same rules and geist apply to Access. However CreateOLEObject and Variant vars would better be substituted by `TAccessApplication` component and related types.

Also search for VBA examples for Access, or even make one (if Access has code auto-generation, like Excel's and Word's "Record Macro" menu) - since VBA documentation for MS Office objects is the documentation of TAccessApplication and VBA code is almost literally translated to Delphi code, except for few quirks that you can learn from other COM examples.

Also https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=Delphi+TAccessApplication&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest

*And BTW, which is your Delphi version ? You'd edit your question and add Delphi version into **tags**.*

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea suggest COM to interop with an Access database. It might be good to work with the Access application, but not with the database itself. [no voting here]

Comment: @TLama given the quite weird restrictions on `TDataSet`... The only other variant seesm to be dropping `TADOxxxx` (which belong to db-aware components sets) and using `OleVariant` with `CreateOLEObject` to use pure OLE DB with late binding. While it might be better performance-wise, i think for both developing and debugging it would be much worse. Using Access COM server, would sacrifice performance, but is a practical workaround of given limitations.

Comment: @Arioch'The, Using the `TAccessApplication` requires MS-Access to be installed on the client machine, and does not suit the purpose of this Q. I also dont see how `VBA` is related here. If you want to manipulate MS-ACCESS DataBase via COM interop use OLE DB/ADO `ADODB.connection` and `ADODB.recordset` objects directly with `CreateOLEObject`.

Comment: @kobik it seems that Windows/MDAC supplied drivers do not support modern Access database format (ACE-based). And while topic starter is free to try working with raw OLE DB late-binding interface, i still think that would be harder to develop. However we don't have info about his requirements and environment..